# Google Apps Script throwing e-mail failure notification for getLastRow, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following Google Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {

/// VARIABLE DEFINITION  

// Get Spreadsheets
var sursa = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("*"); // *=Using one of my DOCS URL here
var destinatie = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("*"); // *=Using one of my DOCS URL here

// Set Sheets
var foaie_calcul_sursa = sursa.getSheetByName("*"); // *=Using a valid sheet name here
var foaie_calcul_destinatie = destinatie.getSheetByName("*"); // *=Using a valid sheet name here
var foaie_calcul_email = destinatie.getSheetByName("*"); // *=Using a valid sheet name here
var eroare = "!!!EROARE";

// Get target last row
var ultimul_rand_destinatie = foaie_calcul_destinatie.getLastRow();
Logger.log('Ultimul rand destinatie este %s', ultimul_rand_destinatie);
//// STOP VARIABLE DEFINITION
```

The script continues after that with the operations I am doing on the sheets.

The script is working fine however I have scheduled it to run daily using a trigger. The problem is that each day no matter if it is a day when it should run or not I am getting the following Google Apps Script Failure notification

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getLastRow" of null. (line 16, file "X")

Maybe I am not calling the getLastRow method as I should, maybe it is a bug considering that the script works fine.

Can someone give me some ideas on why this is happening, or maybe some alternatives I could use to stop this annoying e-mail I get every day?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Either the name of the sheet is wrong in `getSheetByName("sheet name")`, or it's a bug, or your code example isn't showing some other factor.

According to the error, this line:

```
var foaie_calcul_destinatie = destinatie.getSheetByName("*"); // *=Using a valid sheet name here
```

Is not getting a reference to the sheet.  `foaie_calcul_destinatie` is `null`.

If the code wasn't opening up the spreadsheet, you should be getting an error from this line:

```
var destinatie = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("*"); // *=Using one of my DOCS URL here
```

But that's not happening.

There is nothing wrong with the code you've provided, so it's either the name of the sheet, or some kind of bug.

Check for spaces, or upper/lower case differences in the sheet name.

The only lines of code that could affect this issue are below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var destinatie = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("*"); // *=Using one of my DOCS URL here
  var foaie_calcul_destinatie = destinatie.getSheetByName("*"); // *=Using a valid sheet name here
  var ultimul_rand_destinatie = foaie_calcul_destinatie.getLastRow();
}
```

If the name of the sheet is correct, then it's some kind of bug.  Do you have a sheet name that has a space in it?  If that's the case, try replacing the space with an underbar.  E.g. "Data_Sheet".

If you find no error on your part, then report the issue to Google.  https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list